# Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! HttpClient ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have implemented an interceptor to add authorization header that i can make seucred api. 
I get an error when i inject this service in any app module
// "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! HttpClient ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1"

// auth interceptor to add authorization bearer

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Auth } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: Auth) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}


// Auth service

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Injectable()
    export class Auth {
      // Store profile object in auth class
      userProfile: Object;
      public token: string;
      constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {
          // set token if saved in local storage
          const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
          this.token = currentUser;
      }
      login(username: string, password: string) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
          .set('Accept', 'application/json');
        const params = new HttpParams().set('username', username).set('password', password)
          .set('grant_type', 'password');
        return this.http.post('http://rrrrr/token', params.toString(),
          { headers }).subscribe(data => {
            this.token = data['access_token'];
          console.log(this.token);
        },
        err => {
          console.log('Error occured');
        });
      }
      getToken() {
        return this.token;
      }
      logout(): void {
          // clear token remove user from local storage to log user out
          this.token = null;
          localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
      }
      public authenticated(): boolean {
        // Check whether the current time is past the
        // access token's expiry time
        const expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
        return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does your `Auth` service depend on `HttpClient`?  If so, then that's a cyclic dependency right there.

Comment: Yes how can i resolve this

Answer (score 2):

Your `Auth` service has a dependency on `HttpClient`, which is causing a circular dependency.

What you could do is break your `Auth` service into two: an `Auth` with most of your existing functionality, and an `AuthContextService` which has your `getToken()` function (and perhaps others).  Your `Auth` service can then depend on your `AuthContextService`, and so can your `AuthInterceptor`.

Edit:  Add some code to try and explain

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthContextService {
    // With getToken() in here, and not in Auth, you can use it in AuthInterceptor
    getToken(): string {
        return 'however you get your token';
    }   
}

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
    constructor (private http: HttpClient, private authContext: AuthContextService) {}

    authenticate(username: string, password: string) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    // Whatever other functions you already have on Auth.
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public authContext: AuthContextService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authContext.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: really hard to follow your answer. could be nice if you can  help me out

Comment: Added a bit of code.  Hopefully that helps explain a bit more.

Comment: so where do i inject all these service??

Comment: In the constructors, as shown.  You will, of course, also need to add them as providers in your module.  You will already have done that for your `Auth` service, so I assumed you would know how...

Comment: i see that you have injected AuthContextService in auth service and done nothing.

Comment: so wher do i send the request to get the token? in the authcontext service or in the auth service?

Comment: I assumed your `Auth` service would actually use the `getToken()` function.  Either post all of your relevant source code, or accept that the answer is also not going to be able to be comprehensive.

Comment: Instead adding my auth code in my question i added in your answer. I have only two service now auth service and auth interceptor service

Comment: I tried your code but where do i write my get token method which is a post request

Comment: The link that Bohdan Khodakivskyi posted https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18224 definitely sheds some light on the subject, and I liked @Mitch's solution here. It differs from what most of the community seems to be doing, but in this answer we keep to normal service conventions rather than "randomly" using the Injector in a service.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18224) with several possible workarounds. It normally occurs in your auth interceptor service.

Changing the way you inject `AuthService` worked for me, see the code snippet below. Please note the usage of `Injector` here and the way you inject you `AuthService` directly in `intercept()` function.

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from 'app/services/auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // inject your AuthService here using Injector
    const auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
    const authHeader = `Bearer ${auth.getToken()}`;
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authHeader),
    });
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}

export const AuthHttpInterceptor = {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AuthInterceptor,
  multi: true,
};
```

Comment: so what does it do? export const AuthHttpInterceptor = {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AuthInterceptor,
  multi: true,
};

Comment: You should import this in you `@NgModule` and provide it like so `providers: [AuthHttpInterceptor]` along with other services you're using. See [this official doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#providing-your-interceptor) for details.

Comment: I tried this and the error is gone. when this is implemented, the call to access token fails.

Comment: What do you mean by `the call to access token fails`? Could you be more specific? Since the error is gone this could be something related to your `AuthService` which is the topic of another discussion

Comment: Hi, I want to implement the interceptor  to access the authorised api but this is modifying my login method in the auth service. Please see my auth code posted in my question.

Comment: This implementation shouldn't modify anything in your `AuthService` other than adding `Authorization header` to all your api calls made with `HttpClient`. Try to save token in localStorage and retrieve it from there.

Comment: The request to access the token fails then how can I save in the local storage

Comment: fetching token can be fine when there is no interceptor service implemented.

Comment: Again, I cannot guess what you mean by `fails` so descriptive error might help here. The problem shouldn't be related to interceptor but it's hard to say when I don't see the error.

Comment: I call this.auth.login method from auth service which is fine in accessing the token without the interceptor service but when the interceptor service is implemented this will not work.

Comment: I think we're going in circles. I won't be able to help you unless you let me see **the actual error**.

Comment: My purpose of implementing authinterceptor is to add the authorization token to the headers for accessing the secured api. The result is that it is working with all the end points except token end point

Answer (score 1):

Just add HttpClientModule to the providers section on app.module.ts

providers: [
HttpClientModule
]

Then you be able to inject HttpClient on any service or component.

Comment: thanks my friend, in my case I had to add it in the module imports.

Answer (score 0):

One common cause of this **cyclic dependency! HttpClient ERROR** is usually associated with a NullInjectorError.

So if you have an accompanying logged error about  **No provider for HttpClient!** I believe this solution would help:

1. Open app.module.ts file of Angular Application.
2. Import HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http.
3. Add HttpClientModule to the @NgModule imports array.

Your AppModule should look like this

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpClientModule,
],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

HttpClient is Angular's mechanism for communicating with a remote server over HTTP. You can check this link for more https://www.thecodebuzz.com/angular-null-injector-error-no-provider-for-httpclient/